unresolved external symbol error When building Expat with CMake on windows
My C++ program uses expat as a dependency. I got errors when I built my program on Github windows-2022 runners. It runs well on Linux/maxOS runners.
I would like to use expat as a static library in my program. Below is how I configure expat in my CMakeLists.txt
set(EXPAT_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
set(EXPAT_MSVC_STATIC_CRT ON)
FetchContent_Declare(
        expat
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/libexpat/libexpat.git
        GIT_TAG  R_2_6_2
        SOURCE_SUBDIR  expat
        SYSTEM
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(expat)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${expat_SOURCE_DIR}/expat/lib)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${expat_BINARY_DIR})
if (WIN32)
    set(Required_Libraries ${Required_Libraries} ${expat_BINARY_DIR}/Release/libexpatMT.lib)
elseif (UNIX)
    set(Required_Libraries ${Required_Libraries} ${expat_BINARY_DIR}/libexpat.a)
else ()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Unsupported operating system")
endif ()

After configuring other libraries, I use target_link_libraries(myprogram PUBLIC ${Required_Libraries}) to link libraries.
Github workflow file
name: Build Windows

on:
  # push:
  #   branches: [main]
  # pull_request:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build Windows
    runs-on: windows-2022
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Configure CMake
        run: |
          mkdir build
          cd build
          cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="/openmp"

      - name: Build
        run: |
          cd build
          cmake --build . --config Release

errors:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\vector(1037,13): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc [D:\a\OSM2GMNS\OSM2GMNS\build\osm2gmnslib.vcxproj]
     Creating library D:/a/OSM2GMNS/OSM2GMNS/build/Release/osm2gmns.lib and object D:/a/OSM2GMNS/OSM2GMNS/build/Release/osm2gmns.exp
osm2gmns_core.lib(osmnetwork.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_XML_ParserCreate referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl osmium::io::detail::XMLParser::run(void)" (?run@XMLParser@detail@io@osmium@@UEAAXXZ) [D:\a\OSM2GMNS\OSM2GMNS\build\osm2gmnslib.vcxproj]
osm2gmns_core.lib(osmnetwork.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_XML_SetEntityDeclHandler referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl osmium::io::detail::XMLParser::run(void)" (?run@XMLParser@detail@io@osmium@@UEAAXXZ) [D:\a\OSM2GMNS\OSM2GMNS\build\osm2gmnslib.vcxproj]
osm2gmns_core.lib(osmnetwork.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_XML_SetElementHandler referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl osmium::io::detail::XMLParser::run(void)" (?run@XMLParser@detail@io@osmium@@UEAAXXZ) [D:\a\OSM2GMNS\OSM2GMNS\build\osm2gmnslib.vcxproj]
osm2gmns_core.lib(osmnetwork.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_XML_SetCharacterDataHandler referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl osmium::io::detail::XMLParser::run(void)" (?run@XMLParser@detail@io@osmium@@UEAAXXZ) [D:\a\OSM2GMNS\OSM2GMNS\build\osm2gmnslib.vcxproj]
osm2gmns_core.lib(osmnetwork.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_XML_SetUserData referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl osmium::io::detail::XMLParser::run(void)" (?run@XMLParser@detail@io@osmium@@UEAAXXZ) [D:\a\OSM2GMNS\OSM2GMNS\build\osm2gmnslib.vcxproj]
osm2gmns_core.lib(osmnetwork.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_XML_Parse referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl osmium::io::detail::XMLParser::run(void)" (?run@XMLParser@detail@io@osmium@@UEAAXXZ) [D:\a\OSM2GMNS\OSM2GMNS\build\osm2gmnslib.vcxproj]
osm2gmns_core.lib(osmnetwork.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_XML_StopParser referenced in function __catch$??$member_wrap@V<lambda_5f407f5e3d7365e1099cfa463fcf29a5>@@@ExpatXMLParser@XMLParser@detail@io@osmium@@AEAAXAEAV1234@$$QEAV<lambda_5f407f5e3d7365e1099cfa463fcf29a5>@@@Z$0 [D:\a\OSM2GMNS\OSM2GMNS\build\osm2gmnslib.vcxproj]
osm2gmns_core.lib(osmnetwork.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_XML_GetErrorCode referenced in function "public: __cdecl osmium::xml_error::xml_error(struct XML_ParserStruct * const &)" (??0xml_error@osmium@@QEAA@AEBQEAUXML_ParserStruct@@@Z) [D:\a\OSM2GMNS\OSM2GMNS\build\osm2gmnslib.vcxproj]
osm2gmns_core.lib(osmnetwork.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_XML_GetCurrentLineNumber referenced in function "public: __cdecl osmium::xml_error::xml_error(struct XML_ParserStruct * const &)" (??0xml_error@osmium@@QEAA@AEBQEAUXML_ParserStruct@@@Z) [D:\a\OSM2GMNS\OSM2GMNS\build\osm2gmnslib.vcxproj]
osm2gmns_core.lib(osmnetwork.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_XML_GetCurrentColumnNumber referenced in function "public: __cdecl osmium::xml_error::xml_error(struct XML_ParserStruct * const &)" (??0xml_error@osmium@@QEAA@AEBQEAUXML_ParserStruct@@@Z) [D:\a\OSM2GMNS\OSM2GMNS\build\osm2gmnslib.vcxproj]
osm2gmns_core.lib(osmnetwork.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_XML_ParserFree referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl osmium::io::detail::XMLParser::run(void)" (?run@XMLParser@detail@io@osmium@@UEAAXXZ) [D:\a\OSM2GMNS\OSM2GMNS\build\osm2gmnslib.vcxproj]
osm2gmns_core.lib(osmnetwork.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_XML_ErrorString referenced in function "public: __cdecl osmium::xml_error::xml_error(struct XML_ParserStruct * const &)" (??0xml_error@osmium@@QEAA@AEBQEAUXML_ParserStruct@@@Z) [D:\a\OSM2GMNS\OSM2GMNS\build\osm2gmnslib.vcxproj]
D:\a\OSM2GMNS\OSM2GMNS\build\Release\osm2gmns.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 12 unresolved externals 


Note: the __imp prefix means "Get this from a DLL", so static linking has failed.

After configuring other libraries, I use target_link_libraries(myprogram PUBLIC ${Required_Libraries}) to link libraries. You should not do that, neither set(Required_Libraries...). You should use target_link_libraries(myprogram expat).

Your previous question was using vcpkg, why have you moved away from that? As you were doing with vcpkg you should use find_package and link to EXPAT::EXPAT which will bring in the correct libraries and set the required defines for static linking

Looks like a confusion between static and dynamic linking to me. Your code is asking for dynamic linking (that's what imp means) but you supplied a static library.
